# Event throw this error: Pusher error: cURL error 7: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 6001

Tags: php, laravel

## UPDATE

**What I have found out so far**
I use Laravel sail for my Laravel 9 application. I have test run the laravel docker all down. and then started my app with `php artisan serve`. And i was able to fire my events. No more curl problem.

Locally I have PHP 8.1.12 running. The sail php container is running 8.1.13. So it must be a **configuration issue**. Either PHP or the webserver.

---

**Original Question**
I am currently working my way into the topic of websockets in Laravel. I have configured everything so far and created a testEvent. I was also able to trigger the event via tinker, so that the client received the message in the view.

Now I wanted to trigger the event from the PostController. And for this I created a function `ws()` where I wanted to fire my event.

```php
// PostController.php
class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function ws() {
        event(new \ApplicationEvents\TestUpdate('{"user_id": "1", "message":42}'));        
    }
}
```

**Problem:** I get the following error message when I then route the controller with the ws method:

`Pusher error: cURL error 7: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 6001 after 0 ms: Connection refused (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for http://127.0.0.1:6001/apps/12345/events?auth_key=abcde&auth_timestamp=1674832800&auth_version=1.0&body_md5=a5a5ea1c4270fbfeb5177d1c55b6b6ff&auth_signature=1f1127439fa366c8666765ab9bc337b8caebcafca617ca0fa0e8cfb1dd381ed7`

**Questions:** 1. What am I doing wrong? and 2. What does this error message mean? 3. Why it working with tinker?

**Notes:** I use Laravel 9 and the websocket package https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets.

*My Event**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class TestUpdate implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $data;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('userBus');
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried it using unit test and see if it is also running fine ?

Comment: @Win So far I have not written any tests. I wanted to implement and test it first and understand websockets and events.

Comment: did you properly setup your event listener inside EventServiceProvider ? and did you use ShouldQueue? if yes , you need to run `artisan queue:work`

Comment: @Win Do I still need to work with an EventServiceProvider in Laravel 9? Then why did it work in Tinker? And secondly why should I put the event in a queue? Can't I just fire the event like that?

Comment: can you share you ApplicationEvents\TestUpdate code ? and did you call event(...) from inside tinker ?  regarding EventServiceProvider, read it https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/events#registering-events-and-listeners

Comment: @Win ok. thank you for the link to the documentation. i will read it right now. I also updated my question and added the  TestUpdate Event class to it.

Comment: @Win Hello :-)! I updated my question. I found out that the problem occurs from laravel sail configuration. Maybe you have an idea?

Comment: If I remove all the redundant stuff from your post there would be nothing left but the error message. What is supposed to be listening on this port? Did you check if it was running? Did you read it's logs?

Comment: @MaxPattern if error originated from laravel sail config , share your current config in question to help us understand what you have done